# can I rewrite this boolean expression in a simpler form?

Tags: language-agnostic

is there a way to rewrite this expression in a simpler (but equivalent) form?

```
!(foo && !bar)
```

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: @MrTux if I was able to understand that article it's unlikely I'd be asking this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, this can be solved with DeMorgan's Laws. The simple rules:

```
!(A && B) <-> !A || !B
```

Think about what this means: `A && B` means "Both A and B are true." Therefore, `!(A && B)` means that "it's **not** the case that both A and B are true" - in other words, one or both of them are false.

```
!(A || B) <-> !A && !B
```

Think about it this way: `(A || B)` means that "either A is true, or B is true (or both A and B are true)." Thus, `!(A || B)` means "it's not the case that either A is true or that B is true" - i.e. neither are true.

Thus,

```
!(foo && !bar)
```

means that it's not the case that both "foo" and "!bar" are true. At least one of them has to be false.

```
!(foo && !bar) -> (!foo || !!bar) -> (!foo || bar)
```

**Important note:** Conventionally (mathematically and in many programming languages) "or" is inclusive or, so `(A || B)` means "either A is true, B is true, or both are true."

One more notation thing: "->" means "implies" (in the mathematical sense) and "<->" means that the statements are equivalent (i.e. they imply each other); this is also sometimes called "if and only if" or simply "iff."